# Kik bot is the only channel not working through MSFT Bot Framework

Tags: azure, bots, botframework, kik

I have a bot deployed to Facebook, Slack, Telegram and GroupMe though Bot Framework, all of which seem to be working fine, but the Kik bot doesn't respond.

I am sure the bot's API Key is properly configured through Kik and the Bot Framework portal.

I've seen some issues with Kik and attachments/cards, but removing them does not solve the issue. (I only have one image that sends when the bot starts.)

Any ideas as to how I can troubleshoot?

Thanks!

https://bots.botframework.com/bot?id=autoCompeteBot

EDIT: Perhaps I should post a new question, but Kik won't approve my bot because they say it won't respond. For their tester, I am getting the error:

```
{"message":"Too many requests for user: 'redacted_user_name'","error":"TooManyRequests"}
```

The tester is trigging this error through regular use, as is friend's iPhone, though when I test it on my Android phone, it works just fine. (And it has been working fine on the other platforms it's deployed to.)

The analytic plugin I use (dashbot - triggered by bot.use()) shows the bot responding as expected.

Any idea what might be causing this or how to correct it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We found a regression bug on Kik today.  The fix should be released shortly.

Comment: hey lars - other users are still having an issue using my kik bot (details above.) not sure if it's related or not, but wanted to ask. thanks!